# How is the CPU symbol resolved in this C sample code?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, solaris, autoconf

I ran into the following code in location.c for the apache jsvc java daemon.

```
char *location_jvm_cfg[] = {
    "$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/jvm.cfg",           /* JDK */
    "$JAVA_HOME/lib/jvm.cfg",               /* JRE */
    "$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/" CPU "/jvm.cfg",   /* JDK */
    "$JAVA_HOME/lib/" CPU "/jvm.cfg",       /* JRE */
    NULL,
};
```

I grepped through the source code to find out the CPU macro is expanded in the code  `"$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/" CPU "/jvm.cfg"` but could not find such a MACRO defined.

I am not really sure if CPU is a C Macro or some other thing that is being configured the autoconf tools.

how is the above CPU value being substituted for the real CPU value?

The problem I am facing is that when I build jsvc on Solaris with `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` set to -m64 the generated 64 bit solaris binary tries to load the jvm .so files from `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/sparc/jvm.cfg` instead of `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/sparcv9/jvm.cfg`

**UPDATE**

Running ./configure that ships with JSVC with the following command line does the right thing

```
configure --with-java=/path/to/jdk1.7.0_45 --host=sparcv9-sun-solaris2.10 CFLAGS="-m64" LDFLAGS="-m64"
```

the extra `--host=sparcv9-sun-solaris2.10` causes the generated gcc command to be

```
gcc -m64 -DOS_SOLARIS -DDSO_DLFCN -DCPU=\"sparcv9\" -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
```

Instead of

```
gcc -m64 -DOS_SOLARIS -DDSO_DLFCN -DCPU=\"sparc\" -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
```

which is what was causing the generated 64 bit jsvc binary to try to link against the 32 bit so files instead of the 64 bit so files.

Comment: Not a `gcc` predefined macro, check your headers or your Makefile.

Comment: @ouah I have not done any C programming in the past 13 years and never on Unix not really sure which headers to look in. Is there some way to force ./configure set the CPU to some specific value.

Comment: @ams If you are using linux, then you can try generate tags with ctags and run gvim  -t CPU and it shows what is it. If necessary I can make answer with some instructions.

Comment: @ams But I'm not sure for 100% that it helps if grep gives nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It absolutely must be a preprocessor define. Nothing else would work in that code.

For making configure use different CPUs, it may be possible that the configure script takes a [configuration triplet](http://airs.com/ian/configure/configure_4.html). That might look like 'i686-unknown-gnu-linux'

Apparently `configure.guess` does the work of figuring this out. If you specify one of these triplets (quadruplets?) on the configure command line it might think it is building in a cross-compiler, but it should work.

Comment: Yup, I blame autotools too.

Comment: @Zan Lynx I am lucky a friend of mine that sits next to me does custom Linux embedded builds and is an auto tools expert he figured out the option in the update to my question. Your explanation is pretty close to his explanation not that I fully understand the explantion. Can you add the command line option to set the triplet and I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The generated configure script adds -DCPU to CFLAGS, based on the value of configure --host, which defaults to configure --build, which defaults to a guessed value.